# How can i achieve the below output in sqlserver?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Input

TABLE 1: Header

```
ID    ITEMNAME    COST
1    MIXEE        1800
2    REFRIZIRATOR    12000
```

TABLE 2 : DETAILS

```
DID  DITEMNAME   DLINE   DCOST
1     MIXEE      1       900
2     MIXEE      2       900
3     REFRIGIRATOR    1    9000
4     REFRIGIRATOR    2   1000
```

Expected OutPut

```
DETAILS

DID  DITEMNAME   DLINE   DCOST
1     MIXEE      1       900
2     MIXEE      2       900
3     REFRIGIRATOR    1    12000
4     REFRIGIRATOR    2   0
```

Explanation : Header table will contains summary sum or line level information or it contains the accurate information and detail table may not contain accurate information cost

so if header table cost and sum of detail table cost is same then i need to keep the records as it is other wise i need to make first line level value is  cost of header table and next line should be zero .

Like this i do have around 80 lacs records in detail table .

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I think I got it. Let me know if it needs any tweaks.

### Your Tables

```
DECLARE @Header  TABLE (ID INT, ItemName VARCHAR(20), Cost INT);
DECLARE @Details TABLE (ID INT, DiteName VARCHAR(20), Dline TINYINT,DCost INT);

INSERT INTO @Header
VALUES  (1,'Mixee',1800),
        (2,'Refridgerator',12000);

INSERT INTO @Details
VALUES  (1,'Mixee',1,900),
        (2,'Mixee',2,900),
        (3,'Refridgerator',1,9000),
        (4,'Refridgerator',2,9000);
```

### Actual Query

```
SELECT  D.ID,
        D.DiteName,
        D.Dline,
        CASE
            WHEN H.Cost = sum_DCost THEN DCost
            ELSE    CASE
                        WHEN D.ID = CA.min_ID THEN H.Cost
                        ELSE 0
                    END
        END AS DCost
FROM @Details AS D
CROSS APPLY (
                SELECT DiteName,SUM(DCost) sum_DCost,MIN(ID) min_ID
                FROM @Details
                WHERE DiteName = D.DiteName
                GROUP BY DiteName
            ) CA
INNER JOIN @Header AS H
ON D.DiteName = H.ItemName
```

Comment: Many thanks Stephan and working as expected and appreciated your help. I could not able to vote you since it is showing the message like i need minimum 15 reputation to vote.

Comment: Oh don't worry I understand! You should be able to mark mine as the answer though so others know your question has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it:

```
SELECT d.ID, d.DITEMNAME, d.DLINE, 
 CASE WHEN SUM(d.DCOST) OVER(PARTITION BY d.DITEMNAME) = h.COST 
      THEN d.DCOST 
      ELSE CASE WHEN d.DLINE = 1 THEN h.COST ELSE 0 END END AS DCOST
FROM Header h
JOIN Details d ON h.ITEMNAME = d.DITEMNAME
```

Comment: Is SUM OVER() supported in SQL 2008 R2?

Comment: Oh I thought it was only 2012 and above. Thanks for the tip!